# How to export data from phpmyadmin as update with single condition?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, export

I am trying to export query table as update in phpmyadmin (query result operations -- bottom of table).

I got data sql file which contain below code

```
UPDATE `productgemstone` 
SET  `product_id` = 1,`stone_weight` = '0.45' 
WHERE `productgemstone`.`product_id` = 1 AND `productgemstone`.`stone_weight` = '0.45';
```

.
.
.

I want data in this format (**NO AND CONDITION FOR WHERE clause**)

```
 UPDATE `productgemstone` 
 SET`stone_weight` = '0.45' 
 WHERE `productgemstone`.`product_id` = '1';.
```

.
.

how can I achieve this using phpmyadmin?

Is it need to write `outfile` function? if yes then how?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: @SupunSilva check my updated question

Comment: You can use unique ID to achieve this. If your product_id is not unique, you have to add autonumber field at the begining of the table. Then use as follows;
    `UPDATE `productgemstone` 
 SET`stone_weight` = '0.45' 
 WHERE `productgemstone`.`auto_number` = '8';.`

Comment: Try to make a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). I can help you more...

Comment: You didnt get my point. These queries are auto generated when i click on export button (first i fire query and then export that data using  query result operation button). I want that queries in my format (2nd format - from question). Current i got in (1st format)

Comment: Make a unique/index one field and see the export query

Comment: May I know the reason why you need to export from phpmyadmin?

Comment: good comment. my problem solved